# JSON_decode returns null

Tags: php, json, wamp

The following `json_decode` returns null.

```
$messages = file_get_contents(json_decode($json_message_goes_here));
```

`$json_message` is like below

```
{"messages":[{"type":"incident.resolve","data":{"incident":{"id":"P4M9D68","incident_number":10723,"created_on":"2015-08-03T14:01:09Z","status":"resolved","pending_actions":[],"html_url":"http://test.com","incident_key":"27fb39e942ea49bcbc63849a4e53b738","service":{"id":"P19F6J5","name":"Wormly","html_url":"some_url","deleted_at":null},"escalation_policy":{"id":"P58IXAM","name":"Default","deleted_at":null},"assigned_to_user":null,"trigger_summary_data":{"subject":"PD2JIRA"},"trigger_details_html_url":"some_url","trigger_type":"web_trigger","last_status_change_on":"2015-08-03T14:01:32Z","last_status_change_by":{"id":"P7ZDR6H","name":"some name","email":"some_email","html_url":"some_url"},"number_of_escalations":0,"resolved_by_user":{"id":"P7ZDR6H","name":"some name","email":"some email","html_url":"some url"},"assigned_to":[],"urgency":"high"}},"id":"260a18e0-39e8-11e5-8dcf-22000ad9bf74","created_on":"2015-08-03T14:01:32Z"}]}
```

Tried validating at the below URL and it shows that it is valid JSON input data
http://jsonlint.com/

Running it on PHP 5.6 wamp server

Comment: Why do you need file_get_contents? Try removing that and just using json_decode

Comment: Even i tried removing file_get_content, json_decode($json_message_goes_here) also giving NULL

Comment: prehaps try using `gettype()` on the json variable. Confirm its not already an object.

Answer (score 4):

The json message looks correct, but why are you using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)? You are not loading a file. Try this:

```
$messages = json_decode($json_message);
```